# Can't find rubygem when it is clearly there?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've just made a little gem and pushed it to `Rubygems.org`:

https://rubygems.org/gems/fragrant_wind

However, I can't seem to download it again, any ideas?

```
$ gem install fragrant_wind
  ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'fragrant_wind' (>= 0) in any repositor
```

Answer (score 2):

Try fixing your gem name. Choose either underscores or hyphens, but don't mix them.

For example you have:

```
# .gemspec
s.name = 'fragrant-wind'
```

Better is:

```
# fragrant_wind.gemspec
s.name = 'fragrant_wind'
```

Edit 1: it works for me to download then install, but it doesn't work via RubyGems.

```
$ gem install fragrant_wind-0.0.2.gem
Successfully installed fragrant_wind-0.0.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for fragrant_wind-0.0.2...
Building YARD (yri) index for fragrant_wind-0.0.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for fragrant_wind-0.0.2...
$ irb
> require 'fragrant_wind'
=> true
> FragrantWind.new.generate
=> "billowing waterfall"
```

Edit 2: it works via bundler too.(Thanks to @Bitterzoet for this)

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "fragrant_wind"

$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing fragrant_wind (0.0.2) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is complete! ...
```

Edit 3: it works now as expected (Monday 10 a.m. PST). My guess is Rubygems was having a delay or glitch due to its own update last night.

Comment: I suspected that may be the case, but I've pushed `0.0.2` which fixes this, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me by downloading it and installing it, but not by doing gem install from rubygems. Perhaps RubyGems is having a name update delay tonight?

Comment: Hmm I'll wait it out for a bit and see. That seems like the most likely option

Comment: The weird thing is, if you add it to a Gemfile and run bundle install it works as well.

Comment: Rubygems itself has been updated as well (http://blog.rubygems.org/2013/02/24/2.0.0-released.html) which could have something to do with this. You could try messaging one of the maintainers on Twitter :-)

Comment: I agree w/ Bitterzoet... twitter msg and/or a good place to post a potential bug in rubygems is https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues